# Firewall password

Tags: firewall

Our earlier system admin left and not reachable any more.I don't know the cisco firwall password.I want to reset our firewall password.Is it possible ?If yes ,how ?

Comment: What model number is the Cisco firewall?

Answer (score 0):

This is the first [link](http://www.buycisco.info/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps221/products_password_recovery09186a0080094773.shtml) from Google, searching "reset cisco password".

Comment: With Cisco it's extremely dependent on model number and optional extras. It can be set up to be effectively impossible to recover without purging all the running configurations (which sucks). Also, Cisco people will make fun of you for confusing a router with a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

These are instructions for Cisco ASA:
http://ezinearticles.com/?Password-Recovery-on-the-Cisco-ASA-Security-Appliance&id=664795

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is likely serial cable access and follow the manual for steps.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the model.
I was able to reset a 830 model through serial port, following some instructions i found on a web.